# Char datatype insertion not working put database record

Tags: apache-nifi

I got an error invalid conversion requested in put database record processor while reading the data from file and loading into table.

I observed one of the table field datatype created as char. When I modify it to varchar datatype I can able to load data using PutDatabaseRecord processor.

Nifi version  I am using is 1.13.2 . Kindly advise me how to load char datatype values via nifi without altering table.

Comment: What is the error message? Show char and varchar column definition. What is the value that is failing to insert? What are the parameters of putdatabaserecord ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into [NIFI-8392](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-8392) or [NIFI-8524](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-8524), I'll try to take a look soon.